# Get A List Of Views From Linked Server Database

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am trying to only execute syntax if the view exists.  This is my code, but it keeps underlining a line saying must declare the variable @vn -- but aren't I declaring it in the line above?

Further insight, #tbl_views is a spreadsheet that is imported, that contains a listing of all possible views, the view may or may not exist.  I am wanting to check if the view exists before querying it, hence the if statement.

```
Declare @vn varchar(MAX)

--More stuff here

while @count > 0 

set @vn = (select top 1 viewname from #tbl_views)

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @vn)

  BEGIN
    --if view exists, let's query it.
    --if the view does not skip it and move on to the next
  END

set @count = @count - 1
```

EDIT ---
This is no longer producing the compile error as my code above, but how can I check the view on a different server than the server I am running the query on?  For example, this query is run on superfly and I need to see if the view exists on leonardo

```
IF EXISTS(select * FROM sys.views where name = @vn)
```

EDIT # 2
Using this syntax -- and yes their is a linked server connection

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM leonardo.production.sys.views where name = @vn)
```

produces this error:

> Msg 7314, Level 16, State 1, Line 321
>   The OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "leonardo" does not
>   contain the table ""production"."sys"."views"". The table either does
>   not exist or the current user does not have permissions on that table.

Comment: Oh I suspect this is just the beginning. You will need dynamic sql here I think.

Comment: Assumng you have a linked server to leonardo: `IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM leanardo.databasename.sys.views...`

Comment: And what possibilities in the error message have you ruled out?

Comment: @AaronBertrand - it is a valid server name, it is a valid database name - both are spelled correctly, the linked server connection does exist.  Outside of that, I do not know what to check.

Comment: Well, what remote login is the linked server connecting as? What rights does that login have on the linked server?

Comment: @vn is not a table variable, it is a varchar(MAX). Check Bacon Bits' answer.

Comment: @SurgeonofDeath - yes I tried this solution and it will break the code when the view does not exist.

Comment: @MasterOfStupidQuestions I am not sure, how it breaks the code when the view does not exists. '@vn' does NOT seem to be a view based on your code. It seems to be a variable. If you are wanting to make sure it has content, then instead of is null, use 'LEN(@vn) > 0'

Comment: @SurgeonofDeath - I just realized something.  leonardo is running sql server 2000 is sys.views a valid function in sql server 2000?

Comment: @MasterOfStupidQuestions, from what it seems it was introduced after 2005 https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190334.aspx

Comment: GRR...so it seems that is my issue then (trying to use a non-existant function).  What would be the proper way to query a linked server to see if the view exists for SQL Server 2000?

Answer (score 0):

Your setting `@vn = ( select top 1 viewname from #tbl_views)`

From my understanding of your question as well as my understanding of SQL. You'll have to have the following code at the top of your query:

```
DECLARE
 @vn datatype
SET @vn = ( select top 1 viewname from #tbl_views)
```

You could also try:

```
DECLARE
     @vn datatype = ( select top 1 viewname from #tbl_views)
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: That was earlier in my code, I just wasn't displaying it

Answer (score 0):

Try `IF (@vn IS NOT NULL)`.  `SELECT * @vn` isn't valid SQL.